# Keras model passing compilation but crashing on Value Error at runtime

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a basic RNN that counts the number of 1's it's seen and returns there sum. This is my first attempt at making an RNN and I'm quite new to ML and Keras so any help or advice is really appreciated!

I've played around with the model and found that using an Embedding layer to feed the 1d data into the LSTM. This allowed the model to compile properly however it is crashing once it tries to perform the first epoch.

```
values = []
answers = []
for i in range(0,5):
    random = randint(1,101)
    values.append([int(x) for x in bin(random)[2:]])
    answers.append(len([ones for ones in values[-1] if ones==1]))
values = np.array(values)
print("shape:",values.shape[0])
print("values:",values)
print("answers:",answers)

RNN = layers.LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(1, 1, input_length = 1))
model.add(RNN(1,return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))

adam = optimizers.adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,
             loss="mean_squared_error")

print (model.summary())
model.fit(values,np.array(answers),epochs=5)
```

output:

```
shape: 5
values: [list([1]) list([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]) list([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
 list([1, 1, 0, 1]) list([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])]
answers: [1, 5, 3, 3, 2]

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_6 (Embedding)      (None, 1, 1)              1         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_33 (LSTM)               (None, 1, 1)              12        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_19 (Flatten)         (None, 1)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_62 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 15
Trainable params: 15
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
```

The layers are pretty basic and connect to each other nicely with the help of Flatten(). However, upon running the code I get a Value error and I can't quite figure out why.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-f5e242474ef9> in <module>
     11 
     12 print (model.summary())
---> 13 model.fit(values,np.array(answers),epochs=5)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 outs = to_list(outs)
    201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2653                 array_vals.append(
   2654                     np.asarray(value,
-> 2655                                dtype=tf.as_dtype(tensor.dtype).as_numpy_dtype))
   2656         if self.feed_dict:
   2657             for key in sorted(self.feed_dict.keys()):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If anyone has a better way that I should format the model/data or general suggestions please comment or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `values = np.array(values)` line. Calling `np.array` on list of list which are of different lengths creates a weird structure of a numpy array of objects (not numbers) which are other numpy arrays with numbers. This eventually gives you the `ValueError`.

Every data batch **must consists of sequences of the same length**. If you do not want the RNN to work with sequences different lengths, it is indeed possible, but you need to add masking (Ctrl+F for "masking" in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) and probably something little bit more complex than a `Sequential`.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the issue, do you by any chance know if there is a way to use a value other than 0 for masking?